# I want to change base 10 number to base 16

Tags: javascript

I'm writing some code(javascript) to change a base 10 number into base 16. I know base 16 have letters if the remainder is between 10 and 15. This is where I am having trouble. I can't change the remainder into the letter.

so far this what I have:

```js
var mynum = 4053,remainder=[];

while (mynum > 0) {

  total = mynum % 16;
  remainder.push(total);
  mynum = Math.floor(mynum / 16);

  switch (total > 9 || total < 16) {
    case total === 10:
      total = "A";
      break;
    case total === 11:
      total = "B";
      break;
    case total === 12:
      total = "C";
      break;
    case total === 13:
      total = "D";
      break;
    case total === 14:
      total = "E";
      break;
    case total === 15:
      total = "F";
      break;
  }

}

console.log(total,remainder)
```

Let's say "mynum" = 4053 then I would get 5,13,15. But I want to get 5,D,F.I also tried using a "for" loop but got the same thing. It feels like i'm close but just missing something something, Can someone please help me?

*mynum is the actual number, total is the remainder, and "remainder" is where i put the remainder's in a list*

Comment: I made you the snippet you could have made too.

Comment: `hex = 4053..toString(16);`

Answer (score 4):

```
hexString = yourNumber.toString(16);
```

it will convert base 10 to base 16

Answer (score 2):

`hexString = yourNumber.toString(16);` is a better way to do it. But going by logic in your code, here is what you got wrong.

This `remainder.push(total);` statement should be after `switch`. In your code it is before `switch`.

```js
mynum = 4053;
remainder = [];

while ( mynum > 0){

  total = mynum % 16;
  mynum = Math.floor(mynum / 16);

  // remainder.push(total);

  switch (total > 9 || total < 16){
      case total === 10:
           total = "A";
           break;
      case total === 11:
           total = "B";
           break;
      case total === 12:
           total = "C";
           break;
      case total === 13:
           total = "D";
           break;
      case total === 14:
           total = "E";
           break;
      case total === 15:
           total = "F";
           break; 
 }
  remainder.push(total); // here
}

console.log(remainder);
```

Comment: Thank you. The little things make a big difference.